# Why are hanged windows deminimizable but not minimizable?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I see that whenever an app like Mac Chrome hangs, the app will show a spinner and stop responding. So that's the same behavior as for Windows, butI've realized an oddity for Mac:

Why is it that the hanged Mac windows can still be moved around and deminimized, yet can't be minimized or closed?

Is there a technical reason/rationale/explanation for this odd behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no technical "law" that requires any of this to be one way or the other, so it all boils down to how the macOS developers chose to build the system. Therefore any rationale or explanation can only be explained by that source - anything else is speculation.

However, I will try to speculate why macOS behaves this way!

To understand the logic, you need to understand how macOS graphical programs work. Much similar to Windows, each running application has what is called an "event loop".

Basically the parts of the operating system responsible for creating the graphical user interface communicates with the each running application by the way of sending messages ("events") to application. Applications works by continually reading these messages from a queue in what is known as an event loop.

Messages could be things like "The user moved the mouse", "The user clicked button X", "The user wants to close window Y", and so on.

When the graphical user interface for a running application hangs, and you get the spinner, this really just means that the application has stopped processing these events. It might have stopped doing so because it has crashed, it is stuck in a infinite loop, or because it is really busy doing something else (that might be fully productive).

The operating system really has no way of telling whether the application is not responding because it has failed, because it is busy with doing stuff, or because the computer is slow. The only heuristics they have is to time it - if too long time has passed, we display the spinner.

Now you could argue that the OS could just close the program, but you might loose valuable data. If you know the program is busy doing something for you, you could wait a few seconds or whatever - the program is back processing events, and you can save your data.

That is most probably why it is left up to the user to decide when "enough is enough", and you want to terminate the program.

Now these events that are processed by program will in modern terms often be processed by delegates. For your question it revolves around the NSWindowDelegate, which basically handles various things that can happen to a window. Note that a window is not the application on macOS - closing the window only closes that window, not the whole program.

If you look at NSWindowDelegate:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdelegate/1419461-windowwillminiaturize

you'll find that programs can respond to events such as "windowWillMiniaturize" (i.e. the user has requested that this window should minimize) and "windowShouldClose" (i.e. the user has requested that this window should close). The program might do something important when it receives these events - something important it needs to do before it is actually closed or minimized.

But what happens when the program isn't processing these events? - The system simply has to stall these operations to ensure that the program gets a chance to react to the events before things happen. Therefore you cannot minimize and close windows while the spinner is visible.

However, note that the delegate doesn't contain a "windowWillDeminiaturize" - only "windowDidDeminiaturize". Therefore macOS doesn't have to stall de-minimizing a window, as it has no obligation to tell the program before it de-minimizes a window. It only has to tell it afterwards!

Comment: Is it that Unix and Windows have the same form of windowing functionality, and the form that you've described in the answer is unique to Mac?

Comment: No, not at all. Windows and Mac have unique windowing systems - i.e. it is not the same. The underlying principle with the event loop is the same though, which is also what I write in my answer. "Unix" is not a specific system, and as such there's not one specific windowing system for "Unix". However, the most commonly used windowing systems on Unix-like systems is based on the same principle with the event-loop. Note that the Mac is a form of Unix system.